# Nicer way of checking for extentions

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file-extension

Hey all i have the following code:

```
Dim validFileTypes As String() = {".bmp", ".gif", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".tif"}

For x = 0 To NumberOfBoxes - 1
        With myTxtData(x)
            If Not Fields("customField" & z).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                If InStr(Fields("customField" & z).Value, "@") <> 0 Then
                    'Lower case the email address
                    .Text = StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase)
                ElseIf InStr(StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase), ".jpg") <> 0 Then
                    'It contains an image!
                Else
                    .Text = StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                End If
  etc etc.....
```

Instead of me checking this way:

```
ElseIf InStr(StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase), ".jpg") <> 0 
OR InStr(StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase), ".png") <> 0 
OR InStr(StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase), ".gif") <> 0 
...etc...
```

How can i use my defined **validFileTypes** to do the same but with less code?

Comment: See the `Any` (from IEnumerable) or `Contains` (from IList?) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to possibly add a little code, but this should get you down the right path:

```
Dim isImage as Boolean = False

For each validFileType in validFileTypes
     If InStr(StrConv(Fields("customField" & z).Value, VbStrConv.Lowercase), validFileType) <> 0 Then
         isImage = True
     End If
Next
```

Comment: I can not place that inside within an IF. I have to first see if it has a image extension before knowing that. That was the whole problem with trying to search within the IF without multiple If's.

Comment: I will make a slight modification that might fit the bill.